# Are binary tree nodes passed by reference?

Tags: c#, data-structures, reference

```
    static int GetCount(BinTreeNode<int> L)
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (L != null)
        {
            count++;
            L = L.GetRight();
        }
        return count;
    }
```

I have the method GetCount().
Now, BinTreeNode is a class that has the members: right, left and info.
for some reason, in the main function

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t2 = new BinTreeNode<int>(null, 1, new BinTreeNode<int>(null, 2, new BinTreeNode<int>(null, 3, null)));  
        //Console.WriteLine(TreeLessThanTree(t1, t2));
        Console.WriteLine(GetCount(t2));
        Console.WriteLine(t2.GetInfo()); // this prints 1
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

This is weird, since in the function GetCount(), L (which is passed by reference) is changed to null.

Why wasn't t2 passed by reference? Why didn't t2 change?

Answer (score 3):

The *reference* is passed *by value*. Meaning: the *value* of `t2` is *essentially* just a pointer that happens to be the address of an object; when it is passed *by value*, the **pointer** (i.e. 4 or 8 bytes) is copied and passed in. It doesn't matter what the `GetCount` does with the local copy of the pointer: the change to the **pointer** is not observed at the call-site. However, if the method changes the object *at the end of the pointer*, then *those* changes will be observable.

Answer (score 0):

The object is passed in the method. Every changes done in the properties of that object will be kept.

However, if you set something else to the **local** variable in the method, the original object won't be changed. If you want to change the variable, you have to explicitely use the `ref` keyword.

In example :

```
public class A
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    // This is a local variable. If you set something else to this one, the original won't be changed
    //                              |
    //                              V
    public static void DoSomething(A a)
    {
        a.Foo = "42"; // <---- This changes the property in the original
        a = new A     // <---- This sets something to the local variable a
        {
            Foo = "Hello world"
        };
    }

    // This variable is passed by references. If you set something else to this one, the original will be changed
    //                                  |    |
    //                                  V    V
    public static void DoSomethingElse(ref A a)
    {
        a.Foo = "42"; // <---- This changes the property in the original
        a = new A     // <---- This sets something to the original
        {
            Foo = "Hello world"
        };
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = new A
        {
            Foo = "Bar"
        };
        DoSomething(a);

        Console.WriteLine(a.Foo); // This outputs 42

        // notice this --v
        DoSomethingElse(ref a);

        Console.WriteLine(a.Foo); // This outputs Hello world
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it is kinda hard to understand the concept of reference as a beginner, and you helped me a lot. I always wondered why the method Array.Resize requires the array to be passed with the ref keyword, and now I understand why.